# How to fix this code to choose only text files?

Tags: batch, java, batch-file, cmd.exe, html

I am running a batch program to pick out the text files from a dialog window, but it's picking all type of files instead.

**The batch file I'm running:**

```
    set dialog="about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject
    set dialog=%dialog%('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);
    set dialog=%dialog%close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>"

    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe %dialog%') do set "file=%%p"
    echo selected  file is : "%file%"
    pause
```

**Expected output:**

The pop up file browser must only choose text files `*.txt` instead all files `*.*`

Comment: maybe accept attribute mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file helps